# Added NgGrid Break Jasmine Tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, ng-grid

Working on my first angularjs project and using jasmine for tests.  Everything was working great until I added ngGrid.  The site still works fine, but all my unit tests started failing.  I realize that I am probably not doing it exactly right since it is my first attempt.  Keep in mind that none of the unit tests are testing things with ngGrid and I didn't change anything yet with the unit tests after adding NgGrid except including the reference path to the nggrid js file.

The error I get when the tests run - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'createController()')

I have an app.js file with this (If I remove the 'ngGrid' everthing works fine:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
```

I have a Index.js page that starts out like this:

```
    app.controller('IndexController', function ($scope, $http) {
    ...
    }


One of the tests start with:

    describe('test #1', function () {

        var $httpBackend, $scope, createController;

        beforeEach(module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

            var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

            createController = function () {
                return $controller('IndexController', { '$scope': $scope });
            };

            $scope.config = {
                contextPath: '/'
            };







        it('Should populate cascading dropdowns properly', function () {
            var controller = createController();
...
}});
```

Comment: Are sure ngGrid is loading correctly check the reference path for nggrid is correct? Try something like angular.module('ngGrid') and see if it returns the module correctly. It will throw error if not defined

Comment: As a work around I have create a app.js and a app.test.js the test one does not have the ngGrid portion.